# In Tensorflow - Is it possible to lock specific convolution filters in a layer, or to remove them altogether?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

When using transfer learning in Tensorflow, I know that one can lock layers from further training, by doing:

```py
for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Is it possible to lock specific filters in the layer instead?
As in - if the whole layer contains 64 filters, is it possible to:

- lock only some of them, that seem to contain reasonable filters and
  re-train the ones that do not?

OR

- remove the unreasonably-looking filters from layers and retrain without them ?
  (for instance to see if the retrained filters will change a lot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to implement custom layer that splits convolution into separate `number of filters` convolutions and sets each channel (which is a convolution with one output channel) to `trainable` or to `not trainable`. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Conv2DExtended(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        self.filters = filters
        self.conv_layers = [tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size, **kwargs) for _ in range(filters)]
        super().__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        _ = [l.build(input_shape) for l in self.conv_layers]
        super().build(input_shape)

    def set_trainable(self, channels):
        """Sets trainable channels."""
        for i in channels:
            self.conv_layers[i].trainable = True

    def set_non_trainable(self, channels):
        """Sets not trainable channels."""
        for i in channels:
            self.conv_layers[i].trainable = False

    def call(self, inputs):
        results = [l(inputs) for l in self.conv_layers]
        return tf.concat(results, -1)
```

And usage example:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((28, 28, 1))
conv = Conv2DExtended(filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3))
conv.set_non_trainable([1, 2]) # only channels 0 and 3 are trainable
res = conv(inputs)
res = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(res)
res = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)(res)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, res)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 28, 28, 1)),
          np.random.randint(0, 2, (10)),
          batch_size=2,
          epochs=5)
```

Comment: So if I get it right, you suggest to create a custom convolution class with channels constructed from the available Conv2D layers, but each with simply 1 object in the layer and the inbuilt .trainable parameter?
As in the new layer is a list of '1-element-layers' that are now working as channels?

Comment: Yes, each convolutional layer with one filter(output channel) and set each such layer to trainable or to not trainable individually.